# Calcuatated Measure Not working against some dimensions

Tags: mdx, business-intelligence, olap-cube

I have a calculated measure whose code is:

```
   COUNT(
   NONEMPTY(
   NONEMPTY(
   [Customer].[CustomerID].[CustomerID]
   , [Measures].[Enrolled Customers])
   , {[Measures].[Sales]}
   )
   )
```

It calaulates the count of customers who are enrolled and are active(i.e buys something). It perfectly works against Date dimension but not against Customer Dimension.It shows the same aggregated value for all members when i drag it to excel.

My Customer Dimension has
CustomerID(properly linked to fact table),
City,
Country/Region Code,
StateProvince Code,
Geography(Hierarchy)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add existing keyword:

```
COUNT(
NONEMPTY(
NONEMPTY(
 existing [Customer].[CustomerID].[CustomerID]
, [Measures].[Enrolled Customers])
, {[Measures].[Sales]}
)
)
```

Comment: Dear tom, Thank you. It works like charm. For future, what are other cases where calculated members may not work against dimensions even if relations are well set?What are the ways that make measures to work for dimensions?? How can we be careful while writhing mdx calculations?

Comment: Then still need your help to share the mdx query that trouble you and we can discuss for details.